# Do Different Enemies Give Different Skullmine Rewards?

Tags: xcom-2

Do different enemies give different skullmining rewards?

For example, would an Advent Officer give better rewards than an Advent Trooper, since the Officer has a higher rank?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The potential hack rewards are defined in `XComGameData_CharacterStats.ini`. When selecting hack rewards, it will group potential rewards, then select a random reward with `SYNC_RAND_STATIC(TempTemplates.Length)`.

In the vanilla game, all advent humanoids have 125 hack defense, regardless of their tier. All advent humanoids have the same potential hack rewards.

- SKULLFeedback: Requires 0 to succeed. Results in the appropriately named effect SKULLOuch.
- ALittleIntel: Requires 23 to succeed. Results in some "SmallIntelCache" loot.
- FacilityLead: Requires 67 to succeed. Results in some "FacilityLeadItem" loot.
- ALotOfIntel: Requires 67 to succeed. Results in some "BigIntelCache" loot.

The selection mechanic will cause the failure condition "Skull feedback", which deals damage to your soldier and "a little intel", which gives you a bit of intel to always appear. It is random which of the options for "facility lead" or "lot of intel" will apear.